# Retrieving/Returning GXT3 Grid Values

Tags: java, grid, gxt, gxt-charts

I have been working  on with a grid element from GXT and have had some trouble trying to get all the data from a grid for further manipulation. For example:

I have a grid that looks like the following

Colors

---

Red

Green

Blue

---

Is there a way to pull all the values from the grid?

Comment: Please, add some code, so we could better understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to retrieve all the data that loaded to grid from the ListStore object that you feed to the Grid constructor. Here is some code snippet:

```
List<YourModelDataClass> listData = listStore.getAll();
foreach(YourModelDataClass md : listData) {
   // do whatever you need to do with the data from your grid
}
```

Hope this could help you. 
Note: this was the code for sencha GXT 3.0.1 above. Just let me know if you need the code for sencha GXT 2.x above.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a shot and get back to you!

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my answer if it is the right one for you. Thanks